# Not created by default settings.xml in $/user/.m2/repository path using Maven

Tags: maven-3

I tried below command its work properly

```
C:\Documents and Settings\users>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0 (r1004208; 2010-10-04 17:20:56+0530)
Java version: 1.6.0_21
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp" version: "5.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

and once I tried to compile simple `HelloWorld.java` program. Its give me below error...

```
C:\my-app>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Quick Start Archetype 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resour
ces-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.454s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov 18 13:08:50 IST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of i
ts dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.ma
ven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3 from central (http://repo1.maven.or
g/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Please any one update me with proper solutions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you really should format your questions better.  Just cutting and pasting without any regard what it would look like when submitted doesn't help you in getting a quick and concise answer.

Second, what exactly is your question?  You subject says one thing, but your text says another.

Now I'll take a stab at both your subject and your text.

As far as the subject is concerned, the settings.xml file is not automatically created by Maven.  You have to create this and configure it the way you want. See this [website](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more info about the settings.xml.

As far as the text is concerned, looks like you do not have access to the [Maven repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/).  This can because by a number things.  The most obvious ones are:

- The repository is not specified in the project's pom.xml file as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).
- The server you are running this on does not have access to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ due to firewall or internet connectivity reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that:

- this was not an intermittent problem
- you didn't get bad metadata (and clean up the entire `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/`)